# How to subtract hours in querydsl?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, querydsl

I need to build following query in query dsl:

```
select * from my_table where (updated_at - interval '5 
hours')::date='2018-04-06' limit 10;
```

But i'm not able to subtract hours.
I'm using Spring framework and using postgres database.

I've wrote this code to create a boolean predicate:

```
StringTemplate dbDate = 
Expressions.stringTemplate("function('DATE_TRUNC', 'day', {0})", 
dateTimePath);
StringTemplate compareDate = 
Expressions.stringTemplate("function('TO_DATE', {0}, {1})", value, 
"YYYY-MM-dd");
new BooleanBuilder(dbDate.eq(compareDate));
```

This above code is basically just comparing dates from db and not subtracting the hours. I need the code to subtract hours.

When I try to subtract hours like this:

```
StringTemplate dbDate = Expressions.stringTemplate("function('DATE_TRUNC', 'day', {0} - interval '5 hours')", dateTimePath);
```

It's giving:  **unexpected token: interval** error

Comment: You can go through this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @RohitChidrewar Yes I went through the above doc but in querydsl i'm not able to do " - interval '5 hours'" Its throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
query.where(Expressions.dateTimeOperation(
        Date.class, Ops.DateTimeOps.ADD_HOURS,
        myTable.updatedAt,
        Expressions.asNumber(-5)).eq(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2018, Month.APRIL, 06))))
        .limit(10L);
```

Comment: When I do this it gives the following error: `function add_hours(timestamp without time zone, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`
I think that's because `add_hours` is not a valid postgres function. :(

Comment: I tested this using postgres 9.5 and querydsl 4.2.1 using both a timestamp and timestamptz. Are you up to date? What datatype is updated_at in your example? I suspect it might be a varchar, in which case we need to cast.

Answer (score -5):

Use the below query

```
select * from my_table where (updated_at - interval '5 
hours')::date='2018-04-06':: date limit 10;
```

As U need to type cast the date also for comparing.

Comment: Huh? I want to write the query in querydsl.